# AddPayment Unknow Product identifier

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I'm using the IAPMaster by rpzzzzz on GitHub - https://github.com/rpzzzzzz/IAPMaster

I've added a consumable in-app purchase to my app on itunesconnect and I gave it a product id "someid".

According to the sample project, I tried to make a purchase -

```
let iap = IAPMaster.sharedInstance
    iap.addPayment(product_id, userIdentifier: nil) { (result) -> () in

        switch result{
        case .Purchased(let productId,let transaction,let paymentQueue):
            print(productId)
            print(transaction)
            print(paymentQueue)

            paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .Failed(let error):
            print(error)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

When I run this code I get an error -

> Error Domain=AddPayment Unknow Product identifier Code=0 "(null)"

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I downloaded and ran the project and found the way to be able to fix the problem. Basically the error you are getting is telling you that you have an unknown `product_id`. In the GitHub repo provided by you, there is some sample code that allows you to call the purchase method.

```
@IBAction func purchase(sender: AnyObject) {
    let iap = IAPMaster.sharedInstance
    iap.addPayment("your_product_id", userIdentifier: nil) { (result) -> () in

        switch result{
        case .Purchased(let productId,let transaction,let paymentQueue):
            print(productId)
            print(transaction)
            print(paymentQueue)
            paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .Failed(let error):
            print(error)
        default:
            break
        }            
    }
}
```

Here, you have to replace the `your_product_id` with your unique id that you obtained from iTunes Connect. You can therefore see that it is this specific line causing the error as it says:
`iap.addPayment("com.irawd.test.30d", userIdentifier: nil) { (result) -> () in ...` addPayment. Once you enter your unique id it runs without a problem and lets you purchase the good. If you'd like to read a really great tutorial about iAPs, [here](http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/) is one from AppCoda.

Hope that helps, Julian!